# is my visa gonna be checked at point B b4 c

Tags: visas, transit

i have my destination visa but not sure the genuinety of it is my destination visa gonna be checked at transit point even if i have 2 boarding passes from my first point and layover of 4 hours only?if yes why

i am travelling to Canada via say london or any other EU country on airport transit at the international transit hall for couple of hours,i am asking if my flight time is up to and passing through the gates to my canada(ongoing flight to destination) will my visa be checked or just the boarding pass i got frommy starting point which were 2(1 for londont flight and 1 for ongoing)
point A(original starting point)is fine cos i am not certain with this visa the guy gave me

Comment: So - just to be clear - while traveling from A to C via B you're wanting to take advantage of a transit-without-visa rule in country B, and this rule applies if you already hold a visa for country C - but your country C visa 'might not be genuine'?

Comment: @Vida Why do you doubt the genuineness of your visa?

Comment: In order to get a halfway useful answer you'll need to tell us _at least_ what the places you're thinking of are. Different countries (and airlines and airports) have different rules. And while you're at it, please add some punctuation and fix the capitalization.

Comment: to brhans i am travelling to Canada via say london on airport transit at the international transit hall for couple of hours,i am asking if my flight time is up to and passing through the gates to my canada(ongoing flight to destination) will my visa be checked or just the boarding pass i got frommy starting point which were 2(1 for londont flight and 1 for ongoing)

Comment: @traveller-YES cos it doesnt seem genuine and the guy is gone

Comment: YES  @ brhans i am a bit suspicious

Comment: @Vida Please edit the new information into the question.

Comment: @Vida How did you apply for the visa and where did you give your biometrics? What is your nationality and where are you travelling from? What’s your intended departure date? If your doubts are serious, you can contact the issuing embassy/consulate to confirm the validity or otherwise

Comment: @traveller,...visa i gave money and the man brought the passport with visa in it.I am flying from Delhi  via europe but dont know which 1 yet and i leave on saturday.

Comment: You're going to get busted for using fake documents and then banned. Don't do it. You can take your passport for visa check before trying this trip which will end in disaster. After getting banned you will **never** be able to travel to those countries again.

Comment: @ The Zealot i am going to check this,are they gonna arrest me when i go to the embassy and they found out its fake? hopefully not.i go tommorrow to check

Comment: Perhaps you should post an image of your visa, with the picture and identifying information blacked out.  At the very least, compare your visa with images you can find online with a search engine.

Comment: @Vida Don't check it at the embassy! If it's fraudulent you will be banned even though you didn't know anything about what the agent did. The airlines can check it for you.

Comment: @TheZealot I think that's extremely unlikely.

Comment: @DJClayworth What is extremely unlikely? You are unaware that visa forms are signed by the applicant, and in this case his agent did so for him? How many different cases have you not seen here and elsewhere of people being banned because their **agent** filled out a form fraudulently which was signed?

Comment: OP doesn't say anything about signing a form. And if this is a fake visa, the most likely scenario is that "the guy" didn't even make an application.

Comment: Also your passport is likely ruined now--if the visa is fake and you remove it, the damage to the page may be noticeable and cause suspicion by immigration agents.

Comment: visa was checked and its FAKE so i am not travelling,now he told me why dont you just go and when u r checked you can seek assylum in that country...idiot thief.i am getting my money back today

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your visa is definitely going to be checked at least once by the airline before you get on the last flight.

Most likely it is going to be checked when you check in for the first flight and boarding passes are issued. It will also probably be checked at the gate of the last leg, definitely if you checked in online, or at a machine.

The people checking you at the gate of the first leg won't necessary know, and probably won't care, that you are flying somewhere else afterwards. The people checking at the gate of the last leg will definitely care that you have a visa for the place you are flying to. The gate check will probably happen even if your documents were checked at checkin.

You can verify the validity of your visa by contacting the embassy that supposedly issued it.

You should be aware that using a false visa is not just an immigration problem but a criminal offense (forgery) and can have some serious consequences. And "I didn't know it was false" is not going to be much of a defense.